# Login screen not appearing after removing KDE

Tags: 13.10, login, lightdm

I've been using Ubuntu 13.10 for about a month now. I decided to give KDE a test run. Unfortunately, it installed the KDE login screen with it. I couldn't stand it, so I spent about half an hour trying to restore the original one.

Nothing worked, until I went in through Synaptic and removed most KDE packages installed. Bad idea. Now, when I boot the computer, I am greeted with a black screen. And by that, I mean the screen has turned off completely. I am able to navigate to a virtual terminal using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Here's the interesting thing; When I go to TTY7, Plymouth is still running. I go to TTY8, and my screen turns off again.

Is there a way I can fix this and get the old login screen back, or is it time to start the preparations for a re-installation? Thanks!

Comment: I tried the instructions on that question, and nothing worked.

Comment: tty1-tty6 are all text sessions. tty7 is your xsession and tty8-tty12 are all black screens normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-depends lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

(Reboot)